# Accessing a map's value is randomly returned undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a map object that has key-pair values like:
1. Key: Java validation error (something like `{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}`)
2. Value: User friendly mapping of that (somehthing like `Cannot leave blank, please fill in a value!`

The following code is what I'm using to map these validation errors to user friendly messages:

```
export const mapErrorMessages = (originalErrorMsg) => {
  let errorMap = new Map();
  errorMap.set('{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}', 'Cannot leave blank, please fill in a value!');
  errorMap.set('{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}', 'Cannot leave unselected, please select a value!');

  return errorMap.get(originalErrorMsg);
};
```

The problem I'm facing is that NotNull will ALWAYS return a value but sometimes NotBlank returns `undefined` which is very confusing. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**EDIT:**
An example of me trying to use this method is:

```
let originalErrorName = errorData.validationErrors[ve].trim();
console.log('originalErrorName: ', originalErrorName, ' and uiFriendlyName: ', mapErrorMessages(originalErrorName));
return (
  <div key={ve} className="frow">
    <div className="col-md-1-4">{ve}: {mapErrorMessages(originalErrorName)}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] that illustrates the problem? Also, I'm a bit curious why you would create a `Map` and then discard it as soon as the function ends, it might be nicer to create the `Map` *once* and access the appropriate value when the function is called

Comment: I know that would be the way to go, but I have this method in a util file which basically has a bunch of methods in it. So no code outside of those methods. I know performance wise it's easier to create it once and just use that but this stays more in-line with my util file methods. Also @CertainPerformance I've added a usage of it above.

Comment: I'm just thinking, if you have `export const mapErrorMessages = (arg) => {`, you could also have `export const mapErrorMessages = (() => { const map = new Map(); /* populate map */ return originalErrorMsg => map.get(originalErrorMsg); })();`

Comment: Have you printed 'originalErrorName' to confirm that you're always sending 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message'?

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll take a look at using that once I figure out why this random bug is occurring!

Comment: @D.Mayen yes, it always has a value which is what's unusual. We are always passing a key to the function and therefore to map.get but sometimes it returns undefined.